# TSQL function to parse text based on keywords?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I need a hand in building a text relevance function using a list of keywords that enters a SQL Server 2008 sproc, and am performing a free-text search which returns a list of table rows.

For each row, I want a function, say "ParseForKeywords(result, listOfKeywords) AS Parsed Result", to build a new string, based on the result field:

listOfkeywords will be a comma or space-delimited list of words.

If the result is larger than say 100 words do the following:
Find the first occurrence of any of the keywords, subtract 5 or 6 words, and begin a new string from there for the length of the result string.

If the result is larger than 200 words, do the same as above, for the next 50 words, then find the next occurrence of any of the keywords, minus 5 or 6 words and append with "...".

What I'm looking for is a starting point, and a bit of advice on where this logic would be best-placed:  on the SQL Server, or let the .Net code do this when populating a DataTable cell?

If doing this in a TSQL function:  I would begin by creating a cursor or CTE to loop through the comma-delimited list of words.  On each pass.  To find the first occurrence of any of the words, I'd have to loop through the number of keywords to find the lowest CHARINDEX() value.

Is there a way to do a WHERE IN ('word1', 'word2', 'word3') ??

Once this is found, I would subtract x # of characters from that charindex value, until I count say, 4 spaces.  I would also need to see if any of those words occur later on in the text, at which point the whole process would repeat.

Looking at this now, it would require at least two functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Typically people don't like to write full working functions at a request. The community can help you debug and architect your function once we have something to work off of. Post what you have so far please.

Comment: Exactly how much per hour are you going to pay me to do that?

Comment: I was actually looking for a starting point.  I've had some time to think about it, and have added my notes above, and would like some advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Put this logic in the code to invoke after you run your query.  Add a new column to the results that contains the ParseForKeywords values.

This is a simpler implementation but will perform bad if you are paging results because ParseForKeywords will be run for every results.

**Option 2:** Create a CLR function and run ParseForKeywords in the query.

This may make your architecture a little more complex but this will perform much better when paging your results.

Comment: Keith, yes, that reminds me that I had considered adding an empty column to the results and do the processing on row-population.  It may be simpler in the end coding it in C#, rather than doing this with TSQL.  As for paging, I'm using MVC so I'll only be requesting, say 10 records at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Best suited for such a task would be a writing a CLR StoredProcedure. There are a lot of examples and guides over the internet.

Comment: This is the way to go. In fact, string processing is one of the best use-cases for CLR in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is actually a very bad place to parse text for keywords unless you are using the Full Text Indexing.  Here is a good overview:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Without building a full-text index, your queries have to parse every string you search over linearly, making this a potentially very slow operation, especially if you have a lot of rows to search.

Another option is to use a package like lucene and do your searching full text searching outside of the database.

Comment: Joe, actually I am using full text indexing as I'm performing searches using CONTAINS, but as listed above, I may go the route of implementing this logic on datarow population.